# Hide some shortcodes on posts from back-end

Tags: plugins, shortcode, site-url, customization

I searched everywhere on the web and I didn't find something that could really help me. Here is my problem;

I use a plugin that provides shortcodes to show a file in a page or a post. For each file I need to write 2-3 shortcodes to change the 'url' part of that shortcode, and depends on the subdomain I am, I want to hide the shortcodes that aren't concerned. I tried some solutions;

First, put each shortcode into a div with a specific class then hide it. Failed

Second, try to add directly a class in the shortcode, try to find it and replace it by an empty string. Failed

Third, try to find the shortcode by the name and modify its url (so an unique shortcode per file). Failed

I don't know which code could work, I took it from some websites ([this one](http://wpthemetutorial.com/2012/02/14/removing-a-specific-shortcode-from-the_content/) and [this one](https://keesiemeijer.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/how-to-remove-specific-shortcodes-from-post-content/) for example) and tried to 'mix' them, but it hasn't worked like I would..

Does someone have a solution ?

Comment: you need to check the `post id`, if match the exclusion, then don't show the shortcode.

Comment: @SoursopTree I don't think I need to check the post_id.. And how do I hide the shortcode ?

Comment: What do you want to hide the shortcode based on?

Comment: @SoursopTree On the subdomain (like product1.domain.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check it like this inside your `php` file:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "product1.domain.com") { // check the current domain
// your shortcode here. use do_shortcode to display the shorcode
}
```

I can help better if you post the codes that handle the shortcode.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to search shortcodes then hide them - shortcodes who are in a post/page _content_ like [pdf-embedder url="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/file.pdf"] and [pdf-embedder url="http://product1.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/file.pdf"] - and I want to hide for example one of them programmatically in functions.php (if I am on http://domain.com/, I need to hide the one that links to http://product1.domain.com/). I can't use do_shortcode() because users will add the shortcodes on their articles.. But thanks for your help ^^